# Why my GET call gets an array with empty objects?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a c# web project that has some REST request to do to get data from the db. My problem is: I have a GET call which return an array of the size of the number of rows returned by the query but every object is empty. While I'm debugging, every object has all the data I need but when the data reach the javascript the array is full of empty object. Where am I wrong?

This is the request on the .js file:

```
$.get("api/giacenzemobile/getGiacenze", function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
```

This is the function on the model file (.cs)

```cs
public static List<GiacenzeMobile> EstraiGiacenzeMobile()
        {
            List<GiacenzeMobile> giacenzeMobile = new List<GiacenzeMobile>();
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = null;

            using (sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Configurazione.ConnessioneDB))
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                string query = "...";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
                SqlDataReader res = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                 while (res.Read())
                {
                    GiacenzeMobile giac = new GiacenzeMobile();
                    giac.IdGiacenza = res.GetInt32(0);
                    //..... set all data ...

                    giacenzeMobile.Add(giac);
                }
                return giacenzeMobile;
            }
        }
```

And this is the controller (.cs):

```cs
public class GiacenzeMobileController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/giacenzemobile/getGiacenze")]
        public IEnumerable<GiacenzeMobile> GetGiacenze()
        {
            return GiacenzeMobile.EstraiGiacenzeMobile();
        }
        //...other code...
    }
```

And this is the result write on the console log:

> Array(6)0: {}1: {}2: {}3: {}4: {}5: {}

**SOLVED**

I didn't set as public the fields of the `GiacenzeMobile` object.

Comment: Are you serializing the returned objects to json or something?  You're returning a type `GiacenzeMobile`

Comment: debug your api, use breakpoints and see what data the endpoint returns when called. that would be step 1. move on from there, step by step.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Nope, but in other instance it works like this.

Comment: How many fields do you have? What is the sql query? can you give example? Did oyu try to step through the code?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I used the breakpoints and until they arrive on javascript the objects are not empty.

Comment: I don't see where you even add your objects to giacenzeMobile list.

Comment: missing `giacenzeMobile.Add(giac);` ?

Comment: And still I would serialize it to json form.

Comment: @maximelian1986 I edited the answer, I forgot `giacenzeMobile.Add(giac);`

Comment: How can I serialize the result to json?

Comment: @vsarunov the query is a simple select and the data I put on the object of the list are the same of the result of the query.

Comment: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(giacenzeMobile);

return Json(new { giacenzeMobile = json });

Comment: I noticed that debugging doesn't follow the code but goes back and forth without reason. Can be the problem? How can I solve?

Comment: Call it with PostMan / curl / etc. to determine whether it’s a server- or client-side issue.

Comment: I solved! It was a server (my) error. I didn't set as public all the fields of the `GiacenzeMobile` object.

Answer (score 0):

If your attributes are private kotlin will not add it to the JsonString when it is deserialized. So make them public or remove the private identifier